# Sending binary data from JavaScript Canvas to C and viceversa

Tags: javascript, c, canvas, binary, cgi

I need to run acgi C program to process JavaScript binary data coming from CANVAS, but I cannot send correctly the binary data. What am I doing wrong? Can you help me? Thank you.

Here is the JS code:

```
imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,300,150);

 function submit() { 
    httpRequest.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/transform.cgi", true);
    httpRequest.send(imgData.data.buffer);
    }

function show(){
var myArray = new ArrayBuffer(imgData.data.length);
myArray=httpRequest.responseText;
var data = new Uint8ClampedArray(myArray);
imgData.data=data;
ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
}
```

Here is the cgi C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cgic.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void read();

int cgiMain() {
    cgiHeaderContentType("text/html");  
    read(); 
    return 0;
}

void read()
{
char *lenstr;   
long len;
lenstr = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
sscanf(lenstr,"%ld",&len);
unsigned char input[len+1];

fread (input,1,len,stdin);
for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    printf("%u", input[i]);
}
```

I'm just trying to send the binary data to C and return it without any change. But I cannot do it and redisplay the image in Canvas. I don't know if the data gets truncated sending it, reading it, or receiving it.